# How can i save shared prefrence in list?

Tags: flutter, dart

i have two class , in first class set sharedPrefrence like this :

```
[{"name":"alex","code":"12345"}]
```

my shared prefrence set method :

```
  Future _shared() async {
  final _customer = {
  "name": _controller1.text,
  "code": _controller2.text,
};
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> customers = [];
  customers.add(_customer);


 final customerEncode = jsonEncode(customers);

 SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 pref.setString("list_customer", customerEncode);

 print(customerEncode);
}
```

and show this list in second class , i want when back to first class and enter name and code , they are add to previous list(keep later data) like this :

```
[{"name":"alex","code":"12345"},{"name":"john","code":"98765"}]
```

how can i do this ?

Comment: The second example you're showing is what you want? "[{"name":"alex","code":"12345"},{"name":"john","code":"98765"}]" that's just a json array... you can literally convert your String back to Json, append your new object and save the whole thing again as String

Answer (score 0):

Create `Customer` Model:

```
class Customer{
  Customer({this.name, this.code});

  String name;
  String code;

  Customer.fromMap(json)
    : name = json['name'].toString(),
      code= json['code'].toString();
}
```

Then, create a method which adds into your `SharedPreferences` list:

```
addIntoList(Customer obj){
    List<Customer> customersList = new List();

    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    // get list from SharedPreferences 
    var customers = pref.getString("list_customer");

    var customersDecode = jsonDecode(customers);
    // loop through your saved array and get them into customersList
    customerDecode.forEach((val) {
      customersList.add(Customer.fromMap(val));
    });
    // at last, add your parameter object
    customersList.add(obj);
    // save list to SharedPreferences 
    pref.setString("list_customer", jsonEncode(customersList));
}
```